Struts2: ConfigurationManager and/or Configuration should not be null
I'm mid way into struts1 to struts2 migration and got the following error. I haven't any solution where to start and how to fix it. It builds successfully and after starting the webapp with tomcat, this error comes up and the deployment fails:
SCHWERWIEGEND [http-nio-8184-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart Ausnahme beim Starten des Filters [struts2]
    ConfigurationManager and/or Configuration should not be null - Class: org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher
File: Dispatcher.java
Method: getContainer
Line: 1162 - org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/Dispatcher.java:1162:-1

web.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
         version="2.4">

    <display-name>xxx</display-name>
    
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>config</param-name>
            <param-value>WEB-INF/struts.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>log4j-init-file</param-name>
            <param-value>WEB-INF/classes/log4j2.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
  

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>InitActionServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>Utilities.InitActionServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>mailhost</param-name>
            <param-value>localhost</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>mailhost-port</param-name>
            <param-value>2525</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>CommonSecret</param-name>
            <param-value>xxx</param-value>
        </init-param>     
        <init-param>
            <param-name>
                xxx
            </param-name>
            <param-value>
                http://localhost:8084/xxx
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>InitActionServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/initAction</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
         
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>
            index.jsp
        </welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    
    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>xxx</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>xxx</web-resource-name>
            <description>protected resources</description>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>xxx</role-name>
            <role-name>xxx</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    </login-config>

    <security-role>
        <description>xxx</description>
        <role-name>xxx</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <description>xxx</description>
        <role-name>xxx</role-name>
    </security-role>

    <distributable/>
</web-app>


config is not a valid init parameter for org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter. If you need to learn more how to use this parameter read this answer.
The configuration file struts.xml should be on classpath. You should read more about suruts.xml:

The core configuration file for the framework is the default (struts.xml) file and should reside on the classpath of the webapp (generally /WEB-INF/classes).


Thanks, that fixed my problem. But know I get the following error:
Unable to display JSP extract. Probably due to an XML parser bug (see Tomcat bug 48498 for details).
Do you know the solution for this bug?

What do you mean by "JSP extract"? JSPs are used as results of struts actions that are executed after the action ends. Do you need to learn more about JSP on Struts?

This error is probably happens if you use a custom tag library that is not comply to JSP version used by the Struts application. Since you are migrating from Struts 1 you should rewrite all custom tags to the new version. Struts has a resource where you can start here.
